# Macro to extract data from one Excel File to another if it meets certain "criteria"

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to the whole macro coding and creating "smart" workbooks and things like that and was wondering if you could help me with a certain macro to extract data from one file to another. The data that is extracted has to meet certain criteria before it is displayed, for example, column 1 contains "issue priority" (like N, NA, TOP NA, or Y) and another column contains the people responsible for these issue, and I want only a certain people and certain types of priorities to be displayed in the file. Obviously want the corresponding data in the other columns to be displayed in the new file as well. Would love it if someone is able to help regarding this issue.

Comment: Would need to see a sample of the data, and a sample of the output. Otherwise it is difficult to understand what you would like. Have you considered recording a macro as you do the work manually?

Comment: Get + Transform could do this without needing VBA, might be easier.